# Gradle and Java 11: Partial module path

Tags: java, gradle, java-11, java-platform-module-system, module-path

I want to modularize my Gradle project with Java 11. Unfortunately, many of my dependencies are not modular yet. As a consequence, my `module-info.java` contains a lot of automatic modules, derived from the dependency names. Also, I followed [this Gradle tutorial](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/) and added this to my `build.gradle`:

```
compileJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}
```

The big problem here is that many dependencies contain the same package names, which triggers the build to fail on numerous instances of type:

```
error: module MMMM.MMMM reads package PPPP.PPPP from both AAAA.AAAA and BBBB.BBBB
```

What I would like to do is **tell Gradle to add the modularized dependencies to the modulepath, and keep the conflicting ones in the classpath**. Is that something possible, and how?

Comment: Sad, this question has been marked as duplicated although none of the alternative answers are satisfactory